# LPC2148 USBMem example : changing the contents of readme.txt file

Tags: arm, usb, microcontroller, keil, lpc

I am playing around with the USBMem example for the MCB214x Board.
Using a hex editor I found the offset (0x800) of the data area on the RAM and wrote the following code to change the data in the readme.txt file.

I created a counter variable and it increments when I press switch sw1. I want to store its value into the file every time I push the switch.

class variables

```
U8 * offset = &Memory[0x800];
int counter=0;
```

now inside main function I wrote following code

```
PINSEL0 = PINSEL0|(0<<15);
IO0DIR = (0<<15);

while (1){
    if(!SW1){
      counter = counter+1;
      LED_On(1<<16);

      *offset = counter;         //line 1
      offset +=4;                // line 2
    } else {LED_Off(1<<16);}
};
```

The problem is that when I run the code on the board the led remains on after I have pressed the switch and the USB device becomes in accessible!
However When I comment out the lines "line 1" and "line 2" and run the code the led switches on and off perfectly fine!

can anybody explain me whats going on wrong here ?

Comment: What's the definition of `Memory` here?

Comment: Memory refers to the RAM storage on the board. You can download the project sample here [link](http://www.keil.com/download/docs/307.asp)

Comment: OK, so I have to go download some project, sift through dozens of files to work out that it seems to depend on `extern` definitions from God knows what BSP, be lucky enough that there are some build artefacts in there, unpick symbols from the map file, go download the TRM for that micro and correlate everything all just to work out that the address in question is about halfway up the RAM? No; can't be bothered. Consider what you do on every iteration of that loop, and how many _thousands_ of iterations run during the tens/hundreds of milliseconds the switch is pressed for.

Comment: @Notlikethat Brilliant rant :) Linus's style, almost.

Comment: @Notlikethat I thought u might be familiar with the example code since u seemed to be interested in giving answer to the question! :P

Nevermind! thanks for ur suggestion man! I think I got the problem idea and would work on that, Probably now I will be using interrupts to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is "line 2". Just adding 4 will make `offset` run to the end of RAM *very* fast. Accessing beyond the end will probably trigger a fault.

Keep in mind that even a short a button press will be in the order of several ms, and the loop has no delays and is only a few instructions long.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!!